# Android 11 background FCM with data only and screen off

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-11

On Android 11 only, when the app is in the background and the screen is off, high priority push messages are not received for 10 - 30 minutes.

This is exhibited on a Pixel 4XL running Android 11.
General battery optimizations are off.
App specific battery optimizations have also been turned off.
The device is connected to a WiFi network. The same behaviour is shown on a 4G connection.

From what I understand of the documentation, high priority fcm messages should be delivered immediately and are not restricted to doze cycles.

Even if it was a doze cycle, this behaviour is still evident within 3 minutes of turning the screen off, which is not enough time for deep doze to activate.

The fcm messages work fine while the device is plugged in.

How would I allow my app to receive push messages in a timely manner?

The notification node of the payload is not provided. Only data.
The priority is set to high.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: No sorry, it's still a problem that affects production apps :(

Comment: We're experiencing the exact same issue on Android 10 on at least Motorola Moto g6 and g8. Have you tried other solutions since?

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same problem in Android 11 especially on Moto G6 & G8.
Since FCM was backbone for our application, so I came up with this

```
  class YourFCMServiceClass : FirebaseMessagingService(){
  override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
//Your handler Code
}
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            val CHANNEL_ID = "your_channel_id"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "channel_name",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
            )
            (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
                channel
            )
            val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build()
            startForeground(1, notification)
        }
    }


}
```

Then start the FCM service manually as `foreground service`

and also [implement](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) a `BroadcastReceiver` for device `reboot` and again start the service manually as `foreground service`

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        conetxt.startForegroundService(Intent(context, YourFCMServiceClass::class.java))
        
    }
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: And also, do not forget to clear cache and storage of application before installing new build of the application

Comment: `        conetxt.startForegroundService(Intent(context, YourFCMServiceClass::class.java))
` solved the issue?

Comment: It did solve the issue